# Why doesn't my JS play another song after the first one is finished?

Tags: javascript, html, json

On my website, I have a JavaScript that plays a random song from a playlist that's supposed to play at a certain time and when its finished, it selects another one. However, when the first song finishes, it does not select another one.

Here is the JavaScript:

```
const playlist = [{
    name: 'earlyMorning',
    times: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    songs: ["audio/early_morning/cacoon.mp3", "audio/early_morning/reggae_paradise.mp3", "audio/early_morning/universal_dream.mp3", "audio/exclusive/mellow.mp3", "audio/exclusive/bridge.mp3", "audio/early_morning/1998_trk04.mp3", "audio/early_morning/adagio.mp3", "audio/early_morning/all_obsessed.mp3", "audio/early_morning/no_saints.mp3", "audio/early_morning/swingin_partay.mp3"]
},
{
    name: 'morning',
    times: [6, 7, 8, 9],
    songs: ["audio/morning/universal_dream.mp3", "audio/exclusive/bridge.mp3", "audio/morning/1998_trk04.mp3", "audio/morning/cool_groovings.mp3", "audio/morning/game_on.mp3", "audio/morning/half_pipe.mp3", "audio/morning/hope.mp3", "audio/morning/internationale!.mp3", "audio/morning/move_it.mp3", "audio/morning/muted.mp3", "audio/morning/no_saints.mp3", "audio/morning/swingin_partay.mp3"]
},
{
    name: 'primetime',
    times: [19, 20, 21],
    songs: ["audio/exclusive/sky_prologue.mp3", "audio/exclusive/rise_up.mp3", "audio/exclusive/lo-fi_night.mp3", "audio/exclusive/primetime.mp3", "audio/exclusive/the_final_showdown.mp3", "audio/exclusive/cine2020(edit).mp3", "audio/primetime/1998_trk04.mp3", "audio/primetime/apocalypse(remix).mp3", "audio/primetime/bondicular(remix).mp3", "audio/primetime/choir_of_impending_breakbeat.mp3", "audio/primetime/cine2000.mp3", "audio/primetime/kompressor(remix).mp3", "audio/primetime/no_saints.mp3", "audio/primetime/orchestral_hardcore(remix).mp3", "audio/primetime/orchestral_hardcore.mp3", "audio/primetime/quest.mp3", "audio/primetime/swingin_partay.mp3", "audio/primetime/the_trap.mp3"]
},
{
    name: 'daytime',
    times: [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
    songs: ["audio/daytime/summer_vibe.mp3", "audio/daytime/universal_dream.mp3", "audio/exclusive/ocean.mp3", "audio/daytime/1998_trk04.mp3", "audio/exclusive/boombox.mp3", "audio/daytime/2009_trk7.mp3", "audio/daytime/4.mp3", "audio/daytime/connected.mp3", "audio/daytime/funkerama.mp3", "audio/daytime/gritty_groove.mp3", "audio/daytime/internationale!(remix).mp3", "audio/daytime/no_saints.mp3", "audio/daytime/smooth_strings_trip.mp3", "audio/daytime/sunset.mp3", "audio/daytime/swingin_partay.mp3"]
},
{
    name: 'nightclub',
    times: [22, 23],
    songs: ["audio/exclusive/lo-fi_night.mp3", "audio/exclusive/bridge.mp3", "audio/exclusive/the_final_showdown.mp3", "audio/exclusive/prologue.mp3", "audio/exclusive/eclectic_attraction.mp3", "audio/nightclub/adagio.mp3", "audio/nightclub/apocalypse.mp3", "audio/nightclub/dance_9.mp3", "audio/nightclub/internationale!.mp3", "audio/nightclub/nu-soul_village(remix).mp3", "audio/nightclub/obsessive.mp3", "audio/nightclub/universe.mp3"]
}
]

let nowPlaying = null;
const player = document.getElementById("player"); // Get Audio Element
player.autoplay = true;

player.addEventListener("ended", function () {
    player.currentTime = 0;
    console.log(`${selection} ended`);
    player.addEventListener("ended", selectRandom); // Run function when song ends
});

function selectRandom() {
    // destructure object because all we want is the song array
    const { songs } = playlist.find(list => list.times.includes(new Date().getHours()));
    // remove the currently playing song, or nothing if null
    const filteredSongs = songs.filter(song => song != nowPlaying);
    // pick a random song out of the remaining songs
    const selection = filteredSongs[Math.floor(Math.random() * filteredSongs.length)]
    lastSong = selection; // Remember last song
    player.src = selection; // Tell HTML the location of the new Song
    console.log(`Now playing ${selection}`);
}

selectRandom(); // Select initial song
player.play; // Start song
```

Here is how it is initialised in the HTML:

```
<iframe allow="autoplay" style="display:none" id="player" type="audio/mpeg">
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you only set another event listener to the `player` instead of calling the `selectRandom` function. Remove the event listener inside the `ended` event and just call `selectRandom();`

```js
player.addEventListener("ended", function () {
  player.currentTime = 0;
  console.log(`${selection} ended`);
  selectRandom();
});
```

Instead of using an `<iframe>`, which is used for embedded content, use an [`<audio>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) tag like the example below:

```html
<audio style="display:none" id="player" src=""></audio>
```

And at the end of your script you forgot to actually call the `play()` method, which an `<iframe>` does not have, but an `<audio>` element does.

```js
player.play();
```

Note that audio will not automatically play as modern browsers disabled this. Instead you'll need user input to start playing.

```html
<button id="play-song">Play song</button>
```

```js
const playButton = document.getElementById('play-song');
playButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  selectRandom();
  player.play();
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I don't the the actual function works, since nothing is printed in the console either.

Comment: There were more errors in your code. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Is there a way to add autoplay for <audio>? My site needs to have autoplay, since it's a recreation of the Sky EPG which had background music.